# transição e efeito em imagens com display: block de um slideShow

Tags: jquery, css3

Tenho um **slideShow** que estou desenvolvendo.

As **imagens**, estão em `display:none` e quando **clico** nas setas, faço `display: block` na imagem que vai aparecer e `display: none` nas demais.

Gostaria de fazer 2 coisas:

1) Uma **transição**, tipo aparece a **imagem** da vez, **clico** nas **setas** e vai rolando para a **esquerda** ou **direta**, e as imagens (próxima/anterior) vão rolando junto.

2) Um **efeito** tipo um `clarão` quando a imagem chegar na sua posição.

Esses efe**i**tos são possíveis em `display:block`? Como?

Eis o que eu tenho até agora:

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  quantasImagens = $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").length-1;
  contador = 0;
 
  $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior").click(function() {
   contador = contador==quantasImagens ?  -1 : contador;
   contador++;
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").css("display","none");
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").eq(contador).css("display","block");
  });
  
  $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo").click(function() {
   contador = contador==0 ? quantasImagens+1 :  contador;
   contador--;
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").css("display","none");
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").eq(contador).css("display","block");
  });
  
  $("div.slideShow div.contador span.contaSlide").click(function() {
   index = $(this).index();
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").css("display","none");
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").eq(index).css("display","block");
  });
  
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

div.slideShow {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide,
div.slideShow div.contador {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide{
 height:auto;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img:first-child {
 display:block;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior,  
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 50%;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior {
 left: 10%;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo {
 right: 10%;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior span, 
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo span {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior span.boxSpan, 
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo span.boxSpan {
 background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
 opacity: .5;
 z-index: 1;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior span.setaSpan, 
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo span.setaSpan {
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bolder;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 2;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div span.setaSpan:hover + span.boxSpan {
 opacity: 1;
}
div.slideShow div.contador {
 background-color:rgba(240,240,240,.5);
}
div.slideShow div.contador span.contaSlide {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: .5;
}
div.slideShow div.contador span.contaSlide:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideShow">
    <div class="boxSlide">
       <div class="imagens">
       <img src="http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" />
       <img src="http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" />
       <img src="http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" />
       </div>
       <div class="anterior">
          <span class="setaSpan"><</span>
          <span class="boxSpan"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="proximo">
          <span class="setaSpan">></span>
          <span class="boxSpan"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contador">
       <span class="contaSlide">1</span>
       <span class="contaSlide">2</span>
       <span class="contaSlide">3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Pra fazer isso tem que usar `animate()`.