# abertura de ul menu desabilitando o botão

Tags: jquery

tenho uma `select` feita com uma `ul` e estou com o seguinte problema: Quando abro o `select`, ele passa por cima de 2 `botões`.

E, depois disso, ambos `botões` são `desabilitados`.

O que deve estar acontecendo?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    // entrega o primeiro elemento da select option à div .selecionada
    $(".selectOptions .selecionada").html($(".selectOptions select > option:first-child").html());

    /*popula as li's*/
    $(".selectOptions select > option").each(function() {
        //Não exibe a primeira li pois esta já está sendo exibida na .selecionada
        if ($(this).is(':first-child')) $(".selectOptions ul").append("<li value='" + this.value + "' style='display:none;'>" + this.text + "</li>");
        else $(".selectOptions ul").append("<li style='display:block;' value='" + this.value + "'>" + this.text + "</li>");
    });

    //contador de vezes que abre e fecha a ul
    contador = 0;

    $(".selectOptions .selecionada").click(function(e) {

        quantasLis = $(".selectOptions ul li").length;

        if (contador % 2 == 0) {

            $(".selectOptions .selecionada").addClass("setaCima").removeClass("setaBaixo");
            $(".selectOptions ul").css("display", "block");
            $(".selectOptions ul li").slideDown(400);

            if (quantasLis > 4) {
                $(".selectOptions ul").css('height', '175px');
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
            } else {
                $(".selectOptions ul").css('height', (quantasLis*35)+'px');
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "auto");
            }

            janela = $(window).height();

            selecionadaPosicao = $(".selectOptions .selecionada").offset().top;
            selecionadaAltura = $(".selectOptions .selecionada").height();
            ulAltura = $(".selectOptions ul").height();
            janelaScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // distância que a página foi rolada

            posicaoFinal = ulAltura + $(".selectOptions .selecionada").outerHeight();

            total = selecionadaPosicao + selecionadaAltura + ulAltura - janelaScroll;

            if (total >= janela)
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("bottom", posicaoFinal, "important");
            else             
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("bottom", "0", "important");


        } else {

            $(".selectOptions .selecionada").addClass("setaBaixo").removeClass("setaCima");
            $(".selectOptions ul li").slideUp(400, function() {
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
            });
        }

        contador++;

        e.stopPropagation();

    });

    /*ai clicar na li, busca correspondência na select option e o checa (marca)*/
    $('.selectOptions ul li').on('click', function(evt) {
        /*Joga a li selecionada na label .selecionada*/
        $(".selectOptions .selecionada").html($(this).html());
        /*Joga a li selecionada ao topo da ul*/
        $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this));
        // Armazena nome do maos que quer selecionar
        var li = $(this).attr("value");
        // Guarda em opcao o elemento que retornar do filtro que vai testar entre as
        // options possÃ­veis
        var opcao = $('.selectOptions select option').filter(function() {
            // testa entre as options qual delas tem o mesmo conteÃºdo que o desejado
            return $(this).attr('value') === li;
        });
        // Redefine o atributo do elemento encontrado pra selecionado.
        opcao.attr('selected', true);

    });

    // ao clicar em qualquer coissa, fecha a ul caso ela esteja aberta
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if (
            $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y") == "auto" ||
            $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y") == "scroll") {
            $(".selectOptions .selecionada").trigger("click");
        }
    });

});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.selectOptions {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 width:200px;
 height:35px; 
}
.selectOptions select {
 display:none;
}
.selectOptions .selecionada {
 display:block;
 background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
 
}
.selectOptions .selecionada:after {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: "";
 top: 1px;
 right: 1px;
 width: 33px;
 height: 33px;
 background-image: url('http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg');
}
.selectOptions .selecionada.setaBaixo:after {
 background-image: url('http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg');
}
.selectOptions .selecionada.setaCima:after {
 background-image: url('http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/setaCima.jpg');
}

.selectOptions ul {
 position:relative;
 display:none;
 width:100%;
 z-index:3;
}
.selectOptions ul li{
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
}
.selectOptions ul li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
 
}
.selectOptions  ul li:hover{
 background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
.selectOptions ul li,
.selectOptions .selecionada {
 position:relative;
 width:94.1%; /*.01 para encobrir os botões abaixo pois estava dando uma abertura com 94% apenas*/
 height:34px;
 line-height:34px; 
 padding:0 3% 0 3%; 
 border-bottom: rgb(200,200,200) 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectOptions">
  <select required>
    <option value="1">Um</option>
    <option value="2">Dois</option>
    <option value="3">Três</option>
    <option value="4">Quatro</option>
    <option value="5">Cinco</option>
    <option value="6">Seis</option>
    <option value="7">Sete</option>
    <option value="8">Oito</option>
  </select>
  <label class="selecionada"></label>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" class="borderRadiusInputs" value="Enviar" / >
<input type="submit" class="borderRadiusInputs" value="Enviar" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o listbox após fechado continua invisível por cima dos botões, evitando que o cursor do mouse acesse os botões.

Ao fechar a listbox, é preciso diminuir novamente o `height` da listbox:

Lá no `else`, onde tem um `slideUp`, altere o código para o código abaixo setando a listbox para 0:

```
$(".selectOptions ul li").slideUp(400, function() {
    $(".selectOptions ul").css({
        "overflow-y": "hidden",
        "height":"0"

    });
});
```

Comment: exato, obrigado!

Comment: Pode me ajudar nessa outra dúvida fazendo favor? Ou ao menos me dá uma orientação? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247946/transi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-efeito-em-imagens-com-display-block-de-um-slideshow